# Drupal 7 "Lightbox style" gallery with both embedded YouTube and image galleries rendering together

Tags: drupal, youtube, lightbox, colorbox, image-gallery

I am trying to create a gallery in Drupal 7 where I can simultaneously have videos (from youtube) and image galleries next to each other in a lightbox style gallery. So far I have tried both **lightbox2** and **colorbox** but I can't quite seem to get to the last step. I have created a content type and have single images working properly, but I need to have a separate field for youtube videos.  The videos then don't I would like to be able to put both types of content in the same field. I can't seem to find a field type that will allow me to input both types of media that will render them together. The videos are just linked from youtube, not actually hosted on the server. Essentially every "post" should be able to be randomly either an image/image gallery or youtube video.

**tl;dr** Need a gallery in Drupal with a lightbox style that has youtube videos and image galleries being generated in the same field so both type of content render together.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, I believe there is none! You should try it other way by adding separate fields and build the views using them!

Comment: I ended up implementing Media Gallery along with the Media_YouTube module.  I tried lightbox2, colorbox and a slew of others and this module knocks them all out.  I highly recommend this for anybody running into a similar scenerio:
https://drupal.org/project/media_gallery